# How to access name of image that scrapy uploaded to S3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, scrapy, sha1

I know that scrapy use sha1 for image URL as its file name. I want to access the same sha1 that scrapy creates, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the fields `image_urls` and `images` in your item. Then do not forget to set the setting `IMAGES_STORE`.

The images pipeline will store the downloaded file metadata in the `images` field. Like this:

```
{'image_urls': ['https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png',
                'https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAGkl.png'],
 'images': [{'checksum': 'b0974ea6c88740bed353206b279e0827',
             'path': 'full/762f5682798c5854833316fa171c71166e284630.jpg',
             'url': 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png'},
            {'checksum': '9a42f7bd1dc45840312fd49cd08e6a5c',
             'path': 'full/615eabb7b61e79b96ea1ddb34a2ef55c8e0f7ec3.jpg',
             'url': 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAGkl.png'}]}
```

Comment: How would you access the `path` to that image, for CSV export?

Comment: Is it possible to upload the file to a custom location instead of /full directory. A more dynamic path depending on item. Also, can I capture extra info about image like height/ width etc.

Comment: @Rakesh yes, you can override the `file_path` method here https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/pipelines/files.py#L313 For your second question check this method https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/pipelines/files.py#L240